# How to manage file through awk?

Tags: shell, awk

I have file which contain code below like

```
"H","@100",8002,"LLOYDSPHARMACY","Clonskeagh Dublin 14 Tel: 2697086","SCRIPT",20150226  (This is header line)
"M","backdata","1"
"D","GMA",20130101,,0,660C3BA9-E1C0-461B-840B-EDB1670865EA,47211482-AB66-41EE-9907-38B0C72CE497,,"F" (row)
"D","GMB",20130101,,0,660C3BA9-E1C0-461B-840B-EDB1670865EB,47211482-AB66-41EE-9907-38B0C72CE497,,"F" (row)
```

I want output below like same thing I did with cut command it is take so much time I want do only through awk.

Output file like this

```
8002(header)|LLOYDSPHARMACY(header) |660C3BA9-E1C0-461B-840B-EDB1670865EA(Column)|"F"(Column)|"GMA"(Column)
8002(header)|LLOYDSPHARMACY(header) |660C3BA9-E1C0-461B-840B-EDB1670865EB(Column)|"F"(Column)|"GMB"(Column)
```

demo:-

```
    filename=test.txt
    sed -e '1,2d'  $filename > CUT_FILE

    f_1=`cat $filename | cut -d ',' -f3 | head -1`
    f_2=`cat $filename | cut -d ',' -f4 | head -1`

    f_3=`cat CUT_FILE | cut -d ',' -f9`
    f_4=`cat CUT_FILE | cut -d ',' -f2`

echo "$f_1|$f_2|$f_3|$f_4" > test
```

Please help me.

Comment: Can you show your `cut` command?

Comment: plz see above code demo

Comment: Is this related to your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/31079693/1745001? What's the difference between the 2 questions - the subjects are almost identical?

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution, using awk:

```
awk -F , -v OFS="|" 'NR==1{gsub("\"","",$4);myheader=$3"|"$4}{if(NR>2) print myheader,$6,$9,$2}'
```

I used this input data:

```
"H","@100",8002,"LLOYDSPHARMACY","Clonskeagh Dublin 14 Tel: 2697086","SCRIPT",20150226  (This is header line)
"M","backdata","1"
"D","GMA",20130101,,0,660C3BA9-E1C0-461B-840B-EDB1670865EA,47211482-AB66-41EE-9907-38B0C72CE497,,"F"
"D","GMB",20130101,,0,660C3BA9-E1C0-461B-840B-EDB1670865EB,47211482-AB66-41EE-9907-38B0C72CE497,,"F"
```

and I got this results:

```
8002|LLOYDSPHARMACY|660C3BA9-E1C0-461B-840B-EDB1670865EA|"F"|"GMA"
8002|LLOYDSPHARMACY|660C3BA9-E1C0-461B-840B-EDB1670865EB|"F"|"GMB"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to approach this. If your header information is consistent for all records in your file (makes sense), then all you need to do is create the prefix from the header row to apply to the remaining lines. With the prefix created, all you need to do is output the sixth field, ninth field and second field with your fixed text that you can concatenate in the output, e.g.

```bash
awk -F, -v OFS="|" '
  FNR == 1 {                                  # handle 1st record
    id=$3                                     # save ID
    name=substr($4,2,length($4)-2)            # save Name (w/o quotes)
    prefix=id "|" name "|"                    # create prefix for output
    next                                      # skip to next record
  }
  FNR > 2 {                                   # records 3 and on
    print prefix $6, substr($9,1,3), $2       # output prefix and data
  }
' file.txt
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample data in `file.txt`, the output is:

```
8002|LLOYDSPHARMACY|660C3BA9-E1C0-461B-840B-EDB1670865EA|"F"|"GMA"
8002|LLOYDSPHARMACY|660C3BA9-E1C0-461B-840B-EDB1670865EB|"F"|"GMB"
```