# File read through awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have file which contain line below like I want to manage through awk

filename:-test.txt

```
"A","@900",9999,"Test Place","Quayside Sc, Sligo, Tel: 071 9154382","SCRIPT",20150317
```

I want to manage this is as single string "Quayside Sc,Sligo, Tel: 071 9154382"

It automatically take first string before comma when I perform following command

```
echo "A","@900",9999,"Test Place","Quayside Sc, Sligo, Tel: 071 9154382","SCRIPT",20150317 | awk -F ',' '{ print $4 "|" $8 }'
Test Place|SCRIPT
```

Comment: What do you mean by "manage this"? Do you mean print it? The name of the file is irrelevant. Unless your input file always contains exactly 1 line, post a few lines of input and the associated output. Are those last 2 lines the output you want or the output you get but don't want or something else? The way your question is written is getting better but it's still very confusing.

Comment: Is this related to your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/31079200/1745001? What's the difference between the 2 questions - the subjects are almost identical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `FPAT` in gnu-awk you can get whole quoted string as single field:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FPAT="\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]*" } {print $4 ORS $5}' file
"Test Place"
"Quayside Sc, Sligo, Tel: 071 9154382"
```

`FPAT="\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]*"` uses a regex to break down fields surrounded by quotes or separated by comma.

For demo purpose here is each parsed field:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FPAT="\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]*" } {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
         printf "$%d: <%s>\n", i, $i}}' file
$1: <"A">
$2: <"@900">
$3: <9999>
$4: <"Test Place">
$5: <"Quayside Sc, Sligo, Tel: 071 9154382">
$6: <"SCRIPT">
$7: <20150317>
```

---

**Update:** If you don't have gnu-awk 4 then you can use this `perl` command for same effect:

```
perl -F',(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)' -ane 'print $F[3] . "\n" . $F[4] . "\n"' file
"Test Place"
"Quayside Sc, Sligo, Tel: 071 9154382"
```

Comment: thanks for ur replay I got below output after executing in two line Sligo,
Tel:

Comment: I got below output after executing it breaks into two lines Sligo,
Tel:

Comment: I got below output `-bash-3.2# awk 'BEGIN{ FPAT="\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]*" } {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { printf "$%d: <%s>\n", i, $i}}' ak
$1: <"A","@900",9999,"Test>
$2: <Place","Quayside>
$3: <Sc,>
$4: <Sligo,>
$5: <Tel:>
$6: <071>
$7: <9154382","SCRIPT",20150317>`

Comment: This will work only with gnu-awk. What is your awk version. Run `awk --version` command to check.

Comment: GNU Awk 3.1.5
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2005 Free Software Foundation.

Comment: Ah that's the problem, it will require awk 4+ versions. You can upgrade to latest version of awk

Comment: I'm not able to find any awk 4+ version for centos 5.11. Plz let me know if u know any link.

Comment: Anubhava@ When I'm executing through perl I got output with some number like `"Quayside Sc, Sligo, Tel: 071 9154382"00011000`

Comment: Anubhava I got it the solution.